# Parsing xml file with a non registered namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
<mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <mc:Choice xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" Requires="a14">
        ....
```

I have registered the **Choice** namespace using:

```
ET.register_namespace("a14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main")
```

I have also checked the ElementTree's namespace map to make sure it was registered (it is), but I still cannot access the Choice tag. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include the childs that you are not able to parse.

Comment: @ Anand S Kumar I don't think it's relevant. I can't even access the Choice tag.

Comment: have you registered `mc` namespace?

Comment: I had not, but just tried and still not working.

Comment: Can you show an example xml that is not working (do not need complete xml) . And the code that you are using for that.